# SQL Finding Hourly Wage From Annual Salary And Hourly Wage Values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Normally finding hourly wage is simple SQL statement. But, as seen with the data below, the SalaryWage column has values that are stored as yearly wage and hourly wage. I need to sort it by who has the highest hourly wage. Somehow you need to take the SalaryWage column that has the annual wages listed and convert just those values to hourly wage. Then sort via the hourly wage.

This is what I have so far so you can see the names of my tables and such.

```
select EMPLOYEEID, LASTNAME || ', ' || FIRSTNAME As Employee_Name, HIREDATE, SALARYWAGE
from EMPLOYEE;
```

Download the Excel File below
http://www.filedropper.com/book1_6

```
EmployeeID    Employee_Name    HIREDATE    SALARYWAGE
100001        Manaugh, Jim     15-Mar-09   75500
100101        Rosner, Joanne   4-Apr-09    16.3
100103        Bush, Rita       30-Jan-09   85800
```

Comment: To prevent link rot, put a small sample here.   Especially as the particular site you've chosen has a high barrier to entry/use.

Comment: Alright I added in some sample code. I tried to organize the table the best I could using spaces.

Comment: ...Oh, you were serious about there being two different sets of values in that column.  That's going to be an issue now, and far worse problems are waiting to happen.  How are we supposed to know the difference between an hourly wage and a yearly salary?  Once we know which ones need to be converted, how are we supposed to convert it (how to turn it into hourly wage)?  Lastly (I should have though of this earlier)... I'm hoping this isn't _real_, actual employee data (this sort of thing generally shouldn't be published)...

Comment: Indeed, it's a bad design choice to mix the two. Just make them two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column based on a `CASE` expression will make easy work of the data in its present condition, and it can also be referenced in an `ORDER BY` at the same level, so you don't need to push the logic down into a sub-select. That said, I share @Clockwork-Muse's concern about the sanity of using a single column to store either of two different pay types (yearly vs. hourly). I hope the original question is part of a transitory effort to isolate and convert the salary data to use the same pay period.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, LASTNAME || ', ' || FIRSTNAME As Employee_Name,  
HIREDATE, SALARYWAGE,
CASE WHEN (SALARYWAGE > 1000) THEN (salarywage / 2000) 
    ELSE salarywage END     
AS hourlywage
FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY hourlywage DESC;
```

Comment: Yes that code you posted does work and get me the result that I'm looking for! Also just so everyone knows this is all fake data used for a class at school. If it were me I would just have it store the hourly wage and calculate the annual wage when the need arises. I think they were trying to get us to figure out how the 'CASE' function works before teaching us this material.